# UIView with button below

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton, transparent

My question is easy with this drawing :

[image: the UIView]

I have a view above the blue stroke. We can see the buttons behind because this UIView background image is transparent at the left of the button.

My problem is that buttons, behind the views are not clickable.
Is there a way to make them clickable (without playing with adding or removing the view above) ?

Thanks !

Regards,
Sébastien ;)

Comment: of course, but the answer looks obvious: set the `[viewAboveTheBlueStroke setUserInteractionEnabled:false];` because the `UIView` steals the the event handling from the other views what covers it (i.e your buttons) and it won't pass them after.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! How can I accept your comment as the answer to my question ?

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll make an answer and you can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set the

```
[viewAboveTheBlueStroke setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
```

because normally the `UIView` steals the event handling from the other views what it covers (i.e your buttons) and it won't pass them after.

Comment: +1. Since this is Objective C, it would, however, be more correct to set it to NO instead of false (the result is of course the same).

Answer (score 1):

Your image link is broken.

However, you could set the `buttonType` of your `UIBUtton` to `UIButtonTypeCustom`

and then bring them to front:

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFron:myBut];
```

You could also consider add `UIGestureRecognizers` to your image in front instead.